# Is Firestore listener reads unchanged documents from firestore all the time when the listener start?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a phone app that uses Firestore.

I am listening to collection that has 10 documents.

I am running the app the first time and attach the listener to the collection and reads the 10 documents from Firestore.

Now I am restarting the phone and running the app again, and get the 10 documents in my listener.

Is this coming from cache memory / file or I am reading the documents again from Firestore?

Comment: That depends on your implementation.  Do you cache/persist the results of the Firestore call?  It's definitely re-establishing the connections, but whether or not it's re-fetching the data really depends.

Comment: I am not caching the result. I am asking if Firestore is caching the results

Comment: I think Doug answers your questions here: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you perform a query **by default**, the Firebase SDK is going to go to the server to get up-to-date documents.  This query will skip the cache and cost document reads.

The only times a query will definitely use the cache is:

- If you provide a [source option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) that limits the query to use the cache only
- If the app is offline and can't reach the server within a timeout.

It doesn't matter if the app is recently launched or not.  The behavior is always the same.